# Timestamp invalid hour in Java

Tags: java, jpa

I am using JPA with my Java project, and the timestamp is not working very well : it only shows 2015-08-12 00:00:00.0 (the day is correct but the hour is not)

```
@Entity
public class Session implements Serializable {

..
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date timestamp;
..

    public Session(String sessionId) {
        super();
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }

    public Session() {
        super();
        this.timestamp = new Date();
    }

}
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: You should use `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`, a `DATE` is date only (no time, or always 00:00:00)

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you post it as an answer so I can put my topic as fixed ?

Comment: Also, If you're using Java 8+ you might want to consider using the new java.time.Instant class. E.g. for UTC timestamp:

    `Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.getId))`

Comment: @devonlazarus: Why use `atZone(ZoneId.of(...))` instead of just `atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, no reason other than providing a robust demonstration of the APIs. Your code is more concise, for sure.

Comment: I'll leave that honor to the currently accepted answer as it provides more detail than my comment ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [TemporalType.TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#TIMESTAMP) that will map the field to a [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), hence it will contain also time related info, not only regarding date. In comparison, the type you used, [TemporalType.DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#DATE) are mapped to [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), class containing information like day, month year.

So, your code will transform in:

```
@Entity
public class Session implements Serializable {

   ..
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date timestamp;
   ..

   public Session(String sessionId) {
       this.sessionId = sessionId;
       this.timestamp = new Date();
   }

   public Session() {
       this.timestamp = new Date();
   }
}
```